# How to intercept incoming SMS and/or WAP_PUSH in Android KitKat with non-default app?

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat, mms

With new SMS Api introduced in KitKat, my app is not able to read incoming sms and mms anymore.

I add permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
```

and set these properties in my receiver

```
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.sic" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Still it exists a way to do that?

Thanks, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS` and `android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH but my receiver is not notified.